# Postgresql Not equal to string

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have a column `get_parameter` in my table `comments`.

A `get_parameter` is a string that looks like this:

`number1=7013448034`

I need to extract the number from the above so that I'm left with just `7013448034`.

How can I select that substring and get rid of `number1=` using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(get_parameter from '[0-9]*$') FROM comments
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it. I think using the array functions might be useful.

```
SELECT num[2] FROM (SELECT regexp_split_to_array('number1=7013448034', E'=') as num) as query;
```

Check out

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

for more information.